# How to catch OperationalError that happened anywhere in Pyramid+SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, exception, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have a typical Pyramid+SQLAlchemy+Postgres app. In stress testing or during moments of exceptional load and with low `max_connections` setting in PG it might happen that `OperationalException` is raised:

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
```

Now, obviously I do not want to do this *everywhere*:

```
try:
    DBSession.query(Item)...
except OperationalError as e:
    log.error(...)
```

Is there some way of catching this exception "globally" to be properly handled?

My app uses `ZopeTransactionExtension` in typical Pyramid manner:

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
```

Comment: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_exclog/en/latest/ might scratch your itch, or create a custom [tween](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/hooks.html#registering-tweens).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to develop a tween that can do this (example):

```
def catch_pg_exc_tween_factory(handler, registry):
    def catch_pg_exc_tween_clos(request):
        response = None
        try:
            response = handler(request)
        except Exception as e:
            log.error('\n\n\n +++ problem: %s', e)
        return response
    return catch_pg_exc_tween_clos
```

The strange thing is that nothing but explicit tween ordering in `development.ini` works (no amount of `over=` or `under=` tuning of `config.add_tween` call seems to have worked):

```
pyramid.tweens = pyramid_debugtoolbar.toolbar_tween_factory
                 pyramid.tweens.excview_tween_factory
                 pyramid_tm.tm_tween_factory
                 mypkg.util.tweens.catch_pg_exc_tween_factory
```